# ssh bash completion : sed: -e expression #1, char 97: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete, ssh-config

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

The ssh bash completion on any Host of the file `~/.ssh/config` does not work :

```
$ ssh b2sed: -e expression #1, char 97: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

The package for the ssh completion, is already installed :

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh
bash-completion: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh
```

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, I have just seen that `sed` is aliased to `\sed -E` on my system. I'm searching where in the bash-completions scripts, this particular `sed` call is done ...

Comment: @Kusalananda I found a way but I think it is not recommanded, please see my EDIT1

Comment: You should submit a bug report so that it's fixed in the bash-completion package.  Your fix is correct and what the function should have used from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I found that on my system, `sed` is aliased to `sed -E`

So instead of removing this alias which I use quite a lot actually, I decided to update the `_known_hosts_real` function in the `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` script (which I think is not really recommanded) :

```
$ type _known_hosts_real | grep -w sed
        local hosts=$( sed -ne 's/^[ \t]*[Hh][Oo][Ss][Tt]\([Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]\)\{0,1\}['"$'\t '"']\{1,\}\([^#*?]*\)\(#.*\)\{0,1\}$/\2/p' "${config[@]}" );
```

by replacing `sed -ne` by `command sed -ne`, this way :

```
# append any available aliases from config files
if [[ ${#config[@]} -gt 0 && -n "$aliases" ]]; then
    local hosts=$( command sed -ne 's/^[ \t]*[Hh][Oo][Ss][Tt]\([Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]\)\{0,1\}['"$'\t '"']\{1,\}\([^#*?]*\)\(#.*\)\{0,1\}$/\2/p' "${config[@]}" )
    COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -P "$prefix$user" \
        -S "$suffix" -W "$hosts" -- "$cur" ) )
fi
```

However, those changes are going to be lost when the `bash-completion` package gets updated.